# How to middle align cell value in PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I want to align the cell value to the middle. My output looks like this:-

[image: Current output]

My expected output should be this:

[image: Desired output]

I want every column to be in the center. I tried the following code:

```
$styleArray = [
    'font' => [
        'bold' => true,
    ],
    'alignment' => [
        'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
    ],
    'fill' => [
        'fillType' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'startColor' => [
            'argb' => '0070C0',
        ],
        'endColor' => [
            'argb' => '0070C0',
        ],
    ],
];

$spreadsheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(10);
```

I tried all the other attributes like `HORIZONTAL_CENTER`, `RIGHT`, `LEFT`, `JUSTIFY`, etc. How can I do this properly?

Comment: probably a few reasons why you could have recieved a downvote: (a) you haven't provided the definitions of key variables (`$template['start_from']`, `$template['start_to']`, `$attribute[]`, etc.), and (b) lack of percieved research effort (the docs are freely available and describe specifically how to achieve this)

Comment: actually these are my database values if i add more description they will try to add only approiate info

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're setting the wrong (and one too few) key(s) for the `alignment` setting. What you're attempting to achieve is the *vertical* **and** *horizontal* alignment of the text.

```
'alignment' => [
    'vertical' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
    'horizontal' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
],
```

[<sup>PhpSpreadsheet docs</sup>](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#formatting-cells)

Comment: i used for testing purpose i have reoved still same output

Comment: @kunal - Did you _remove_ the `alignment` property or did you _change_ it to be `vertical` instead of `horizontal` as this answer suggests?

Comment: @kunal - You might need to set both `horizontal` and `vertical` as centered.

Comment: kunal - Please see updated answer with @MagnusEriksson's suggestion

Answer (score 8):

Beyond the [style array way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55141364/1494454) you can also do it in the method chaining way:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cells)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal($align)

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cells)->getAlignment()->setVertical($align);
```

- `$cells` should be a single cell (`'A1'`) or a range of cells (`'A1:E4'`).
- `$align` should be a constant of the `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment` class (or its string value) for the desired alignment.

  - for horizontal alignment:

    - `Alignment::HORIZONTAL_GENERAL` or `'general'`
    - `Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT` or `'left'`
    - `Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT` or `'right'`
    - `Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER` or `'center'`
    - `Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER_CONTINUOUS` or `'centerContinuous'`
    - `Alignment::HORIZONTAL_JUSTIFY` or `'justify'`
    - `Alignment::HORIZONTAL_FILL` or `'fill'`
    - `Alignment::HORIZONTAL_DISTRIBUTED` or `'distributed'` (Excel2007 only)
  - for vertical alignment:

    - `Alignment::VERTICAL_BOTTOM` or `'bottom'`
    - `Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP` or `'top'`
    - `Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER` or `'center'`
    - `Alignment::VERTICAL_JUSTIFY` or `'justify'`
    - `Alignment::VERTICAL_DISTRIBUTED` or `'distributed'` (Excel2007 only)

The source of these is the [source](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Style/Alignment.php#L9-L24).